# Truncation of text in Emacs terminal emulators

Tags: ansi-term, term

When I log in to the cluster using `shell` or `eshell`, I get the following message:

> 2018-04-11: The MEM1024 node is now back in the queue. The hardware had to be completely replaced, which means there is now 24 cores available on this node. If you need the full 1024 node, you should therefore use #SBATCH -n 24 as well.
>
> /staff
>
> WARNING! You are over your files quota on "$SNIC_NOBACKUP"!  Grace time remaining: 3w0d2h59m19.0s

However, if I use terminal emulators `term` or `ansi-term`, the same message gets cut as follows:

> 2018-04-11: The MEM1024 node is now back in the queue. The hardware had to be completely replaced, which means there is now 24 cores
>
> [user@host ~]$ r your files quota on "$SNIC_NOBACKUP"!  Grace time remaining: 3w0d0h15m31.0ss well.

I have noticed that when entering `bash` the mini-buffer displays

> Truncate long lines disabled

It does not matter if line warping is enabled or disabled at the launch of `bash` but if I switch it ON and OFF, the issue disappears. Does anyone have suggestions how to fix it? It is tedious to do `M-x toggle-truncate-lines` several times.

**UPD 1:** I run GNU Emacs 26.2 on macOS Mojave 10.14.6. Running `emacs -Q` yields:

```
Emacs-x86_64-10_14[35152:7689947] Failed to initialize color list unarchiver:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: 
non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: 
non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver}
```

I searched for the possible source of this error and [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52534946/3166723) that one needs to delete `~/Library/Colors/Emacs.clr`. Now quick Emacs session starts without errors and more importantly, I do not observe the original problem anymore. Does anyone have a clue what are the implications of this?

Comment: emacs 26.2 on WSL called with `emacs -Q` outputs the full string for `echo "   ! # $ % & ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z   ! # $ % & ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"`. Please give the `emacs-version` text and test with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: smells like a prompt issue. what happens when you move aside your bash init files?

Comment: @Tobias, I updated the post.

Comment: @nega, nothing changes.